# How to fix: adlistener for radio button for if else calculation

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, calculation

I'm trying to create a BMR calculation embedded in my site. I have it working except for the gender portion (if male vs female, different calculations)

I understand that I need an adlistener but doesn't seem to be working. I think I am not referencing it properly.

Here's my code:

```js
var theForm = document.forms["RMRform"];
var bmr;

function RMRcalc() {
  var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
  var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
  var rad = document.myForm.myRadios;
  var prev = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      (prev) ? console.log(prev.value): null;
      if (this !== prev) {
        prev = this;
      }
      console.log(this.value)
    });
  }
  var activitylevel = new Array();
  activitylevel["sedentary"] = 1.2;
  activitylevel["low"] = 1.3;
  activitylevel["moderate"] = 1.5;
  activitylevel["high"] = 1.7;

  function getActivityLevel() {
    var activityLevelamount = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms["RMRform"];
    var selectedActivity = theForm.elements["activity"];
    activityLevelamount = activitylevel[selectedActivity.value];
    return activityLevelamount;
  }

  if (i = this) {
    bmr = ((10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) - 161) * getActivityLevel();
  } else {
    bmr = ((10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5) * getActivityLevel();
  }

}

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  RMRcalc();
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = bmr;

})
```

```css
  body {
  font: 15px gothic, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=number] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

button[type=button] {
  background-color: #ddcecb;
  border: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  color: #95483e;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.form-inline label {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .form-inline input {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .form-inline {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
```

```html
<form action="" id="RMRform">
  <label for='gender' class="inlinelabel">
      Female </label>
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="fem" checked onclick="RMRcalc()" /><br>
  <label for='gender' class="inlinelabel">
      Male </label>
  <input type="radio" id="gender" name='gender' value="masc" onclick="RMRcalc()" /> <br> Weight (kg):<br>
  <input type="number" id="weight"><br><br> Height (cm):<br>
  <input type="number" id="height"><br><br> Age (years):<br>
  <input type="number" id="age"><br><br> Activity Level:
  <select id="activity" name="activity">
    <option value="sedentary">sedentary (1-2x/week)</option>
    <option value="low">low (2-3x/week)</option>
    <option value="moderate">moderate (3-4x/week)</option>
    <option value="high">high (5x/week)</option>
  </select>
</form> <br>

<button type="button" onclick="">
    calculate</button>


<p>Your Daily Estimated Requirements</p>
<div id="results"></div>
```

With this, there's just no calculation showing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var rad = document.myForm.myRadios;` is not valid. Should be `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')`

Comment: Tried this but still getting the same answer whether male or female is selected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something in this region...

```js
function calc () {
  const gender   = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value,
        weight   = document.getElementById('weight').value,
        height   = document.getElementById('height').value,
        age      = document.getElementById('age').value,
        activity = document.getElementById('activity').value;

  // calculate base metric value
  let metricBase = ((10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age));
  // calculate per gender
  metricBase = (gender === 'fem') ? metricBase - 161 : metricBase + 5;

  // calculate with inline activity values
  const bmr = Math.round( metricBase * parseFloat(activity) );
  // format caloric intake output
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = `${bmr.toLocaleString()} calories/day`;
}

// prevents form change listener until after first calculation
let firstCalc = true;

document.getElementById('calc').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (firstCalc) document.querySelector('form').onchange = calc;
  firstCalc = false;
  calc();
}, false);
```

```css
body {
}

body, input {
  font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1rem;
}

input[type="number"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.group {
  padding: .5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="group">
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="fem" checked />
      Female
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name='gender' value="masc" />
      Male
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="weight">Weight (kg):</label>
    <input type="number" id="weight" value="79" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="weight">Height (cm):</label>
    <input type="number" id="height" value="172" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="weight">Age (years):</label>
    <input type="number" id="age" value="22" />
  </div>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="activity">Activity Level:</label>
    <select id="activity">
      <option value="1.2" selected>Sedentary (1-2x/week)</option>
      <option value="1.3">Low (2-3x/week)</option>
      <option value="1.5">Moderate (3-4x/week)</option>
      <option value="1.7">High (5x/week)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="calc">Calculate</button>
</form>

<p id="results"></p>
```

Comment: I think this is it! Amazing! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

1. A closing `}` is missing for the `@media` query.
2. There shouldn't be a variable declaration in your `if` condition: `if (var i=this)`. Remove the `var`.
3. Both of your radio `input` have the same `id="gender"`. `Id`'s should be unique. Consider using a `class` instead. This will cause problems when you later use the `gender` variable for your if male vs female calculations because of this selector:

```
   var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
```

4. For `rad` to be defined in your loop...

```
   var rad = document.myForm.myRadios;
```

...you'll need to change `myRadios` to `gender`, because that's the `name` of your radio inputs. You'll also need to give your form the name `myForm`.

```html
    <form action="" id="RMRform" name="myForm">
```

Comment: I fixed all of this but still not getting any calculations.

Comment: Are you getting calculations for one gender or none at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i see (i am quite new to JS so i may not see everything) :

- There is no opening head tag (not sure if that's a problem).
- The gender radio buttons both have the same id. **IDs should be unique**. And because of this my guess is that this code should only give you the value for `fem` no ?:

*html:*

```
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="fem" checked 
    onclick="RMRcalc()" />
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name='gender' value="masc" 
    onclick="RMRcalc()" />
```

*js:*

```
    var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
```

- In your for-loops i would use `let` instead of `var`, otherwise you might get in trouble someday. Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

  ```
  for (let i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
          rad[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
  ```
- I didn't understand this in your function `RMRcalc` : `if (var i = this)`

Comment: Why would `var` cause trouble someday? It's perfectly acceptable to declare iterators this way.

Comment: Yes, I thought of possible closure issues. I edited my answer to clarify what i meant.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. While that's a good point to raise, the code doesn't make use of any anonymous functions or references out of scope within the loop.

Comment: But if i understand correctly, since 'i' isn't used in the addEventListener function() it should work just fine here

Comment: Let's agree to disagree. `var` and `let` both work in the given context. `let` should be a suitable replacement for future reference.

Comment: Yea, that's right- I'm only getting the female calculation; which is why I was looking into the adlistener.

Comment: Still having an issue with the male calculation not being computed when Male radio button is selected.